# (From Axler)Why does the basis satisfy the required conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, change-of-basis

Suppose $w1, ⋯⋯, wn$ is a basis of $W$ and $V$ is finite-dimensional. Suppose $T∈L(V,W)$. Prove that there exists a basis $v1 ⋯⋯, vm$ of $V$ such that all the entries in the first row of $M(T)$ (with respect to the bases $v1, ⋯⋯, vm$ and $w1, ⋯⋯, wn$) are 0 except for possibly a $1$ in the first row, first column.

Here is a proof.

http://linearalgebras.com/3C.html (Q5 in the page)

Could someone explain how to get the basis that I need?
(i.e. the author seems to omit the process of obtaining the answer. He just gives the answer without explanations)

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the books builds $v_i$. The unclear part is the distinction between $\nu_i$ and $v_i$ but the solution is right in front of your eyes.

Comment: But it is not clear how to obtain the answer! The author simply gave away the expression of vi in terms of vi and asked the reader to check the answer.

Comment: Just to be clear: The solutions posted at the website listed above were very definitely not written by the author of Linear Algebra Done Right. Whoever wrote those solutions has not included her or his name on the website above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $T$ is the zero map, the matrix will be the zero matrix.
More generally, if the image of $T$ is in the span of $w_2,\ldots, w_n$, the first row will be all zero, no matter how we choose the basis of $V$.
So we may assume that there exists some $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=a_1w_1+\ldots +a_nw_n$ with $a_1\ne 0$. Then with $v_1:=\frac1{a_1}v$ we will have $T(v_1)=w_1+\ldots$, i.e., a $1$ in the top left.
Now extend $v_1$ to *any* basis $v_1,\tilde v_2.\tilde v_3,\ldots,\tilde v_n$.
We have $T(\tilde v_k)=b_kw_1+\ldots$ and therefore if we let $v_k=\tilde v_k-b_kv_1$, we ensure that $T(v_k)=0\cdot w_1+\ldots$, as desired.
Remains to see that this is a basis. But that is clear because we can obain the $\tilde v_k$ back.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is this: If $T\in L(V,W)$. Let $B=\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ be a basis of $V$ and let $C=\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ the given basis of $W$. Matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$ and $C$ has $Tu_i$'s as columns.  Applying elementary column operations on the matrix won't change the column space of $T$ and the corresponding operations on $u_i$'s won't affect their linear independence.

Let's proceed with the idea developed above. There exist scalars $c_{ij}$'s such that
$Tu_i=\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}w_j$ for every $1\le i\le m$.

Suppose that $k$ is the smallest index in $\{1,2,...,m\}$ such that $c_{1k}\ne 0$.

If such a $k$ doesn't exist, then the required basis is $B$ and we are done.

So WLOG (Refer **Note**)let $k=1$.
Let's let's turn all non zero $c_{1j}$ into $1$ by dividing by appropriate numbers.

Let's define: $u_1':=\frac {u_1}{c_{11}}, u_i':=\frac {u_i}{c_{1i}}$ for those $1\le i\le m$ for which $c_{1i}\ne 0$ and $u_i'=u_i$ for those $1\le i\le m$ for which $c_{1i}=0$.
So now all non zero entries of first row of $T$ are converted to $1$.

To eliminate extra ones, let's again define $u_1'':=u_1', u_i'':=u_i'-u_1'$ for those $2\le i\le m$ such that $(1,i)$th entry of $T$ is non zero and $u_i'':= u_i'$ for those $2\le i\le m$ for which $(1,i)$th entry of $T$ is $0$.

Based on the idea developed in first para, it may be verified that $T(u_i'')'$s are linearly independent.

Note that for any $i\gt 1$, $Tu_i''= Tu_i'-Tu_1'=\frac {Tu_i}{c_{1i}}-\frac{Tu_1}{c_{11}}$ is in span $(w_2,...,w_n)$; and that $Tu_1''$ has coefficient of $w_1$ as $1$.

**NOTE**: If $k$ is not equal to $1$ then we may rearrange $u_i$'s to get $u_1'=u_k, u_i'=u_i$ for $m\ge i\ge 2$ and then instead of $B$, the proof will use $B':=\{u_1',u_2',...,u_m'\}$